# For an irreducible Markov Chain let $P^r(x,y)>0$ and $P^l(y,x)>0$, then if m= r+l follows m ∈ T (x)∩T (y) then how T (x) ⊂ T (y) − m holds true?

Tags: proof-explanation, markov-chains

**Lemma-** If a Markov chain is irreducible, then the period of all states is equal i.e. $gcd T (x) = gcd T (y)$ for all $x, y ∈ X$

**Proof-** Fix two states x and y. There exist non-negative integers r and l such
that
$P^r (x, y) > 0$ and $P^l (y, x) > 0$.
Letting $m = r+l$, we have $m ∈ T (x)∩T (y)$ and
**$T (x) ⊂ T (y) − m$**, whence gcd $T (y)$ divides all elements of $T (x)$. We conclude that
gcd $T (y) ≤ gcd T (x)$. By an entirely parallel argument, $gcd T (x) ≤ gcd T (y)$.
 In this proof can you explain how **$T (x) ⊂ T (y) − m$** is derived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n \in T(x)$, so that $P^n(x,x) > 0$.  Then $$0 < P^l(y,x)P^n(x,x)P^r(x,y) \leq P^{l+n+r}(y,y)$$ shows that $$m+n = l+n+r \in T(y).$$  Therefore $n \in T(y) - m$.  Since $n$ was an arbitrary element of $T(x)$, it follows that $T(x) \subset T(y) - m$.